# Do PostgreSQL triggers execute in the same transaction as the original statement?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

If Table A has a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to `UPDATE` Table B, do those two operations run in the same transaction? Specifically, if the `UPDATE` on Table B fails, does that mean the `INSERT` on Table A is rolled back?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

I couldn't find this in the docs at first, but I just found it in [Overview of Trigger Behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html).

> In all cases, a trigger is executed as part of the same transaction as the statement that triggered it, so if either the statement or the trigger causes an error, the effects of both will be rolled back.